# BASH - Finding the XML from the log file

Tags: xml, bash

Seeking help to extract the XML's from the log file. I have a long log file which is having the multiple XMLs in-between, Would like to extract all the XMLs one-by-one in the each separate output file. The sample contents are as below: the xml does not end in the same line.

```
02132018 15:18:24:: <?xml version="1.0"?><BATCH>many sub tags</BATCH>
```

I need the output from `<BATCH>` onwards.
I tried with the below command, and gives the result in an output file, but it copied all XMLs into 1 output, whereas I want each XML to separate output file.

```
sed -n '/<BATCH>/,/<\/BATCH>/p' $log_file > $ouput_file
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding additional information as comments.

Comment: When you edit your question, please provide:  Example input, desired output, code you've written already to try to solve the problem, and the specific issue you're having problems solving.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)